# Comparing 2 columns in excel to highlight match and difference

Tags: excel, match, vba

I try to match data from my bank statement and data from my erp. The excel looks something like this:
[image: preview]

I want to select the transaction number  given in ERP data column and search it in Bank data column. If there is a match then concat the matched data and print in column D, else print the unmatched data in column E. 
I am trying to use 
`=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B2,$A$3:$A$30,0)),"",B2)` but it's not giving appropriate results.

Comment: "its not giving appropriate results" doesn't help at all. What is your result and what do you expect? Edit your question and provide more details please.

Comment: Also, **concat** to what?

Comment: "its not giving appropriate results" - the formula is not throwing any error. when i run it says data matched.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to return a value. I changed `IF(ISERROR...` to `IFERROR` function which returns the value of first argument if there is no error or the second argument if error occurs. I also used `INDEX` to get the value from column A and concatenate it with value from B.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$A$30,MATCH(B2,$A$3:$A$30,0)) & " " & B2,"")
```

This is formula for column D. In E you just need

```
=IF(D2="",B2,"")
```

Comment: The formula is not working. The data is being searched only in correspondent coloum and not selected A coloum. E.g the data in B2 is being searched only in A2 and not A2 to A30.